# Entity Framework changes decimal separator from passed values to FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I try to execute the following query:

```
dbContext.Datas.FromSqlRaw($"select LD.\"Id\", LD.\"OId\" from public.\"Datas\" LD where ST_Intersects(LD.\"Geometry\", st_geomfromtext('POINT({lat} {lng})'))").Select(l => l.Id);
```

But whenever I'm doing it, I get the following error:

> ""POINT(-1741541,25" <-- parse error at position 17 within geometry"
> Obviously, it changes -1741541.25 to -1741541,25, and it's somehow linked with locale settings. However, my database locale is en-US, therefore it's not database's problem, but I should somehow configure my Entity framework, but I'm not sure how to do it and couldn't find it either. What should I do?

**UPD**: `lat` and `lng` are of type `double` (e.g -1741541.255287818)

I've also tried to do that using `FromSqlInterpolated`

```
dbContext.Datas.FromSqlInterpolated($"select LD.\"Id\", LD.\"OId\" from public.\"Datas\" LD where ST_Intersects(LD.\"Geometry\", st_geomfromtext('POINT({lat} {lng})'))").Select(l => l.Id);
```

But I get this error:

> ""POINT(@p" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry"

Also I'm pretty much sure that my query is correct. Whenever I pass those `lat` and `lng` values into the query string, it works fine.

Comment: What type have lat&lng? If they are not strings use conversion methods of that types to create formatted strings as needed. Presumably an overload of ToString().

Comment: lat and lng are double

Comment: Why are you not using `FromSqlInterpolated`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: `Entity framework changes decimal separator from passes values to FromSqlRaw` To be clear - EF is doing nothing of the sort. `double.ToString` is doing it before EF is even involved.

Comment: I would use SqlParameter for latitude and longitude.

Comment: Can't really figure it out. Whenever I try to pass SqlParameters, it gives me the very same error as with FromSqlInterpolates

Comment: I dealed with this error this morning. ```lat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);``` will solve your issue.

Comment: Actually, works quite well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went through the same situation this morning.

You can force both lat and lng to be formatted with a dot separator with `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Updated after comment:

I'm not really sure, I guess the issue comes from the running Windows Regional settings / Culture as I know that in my region - and on my developing machine - the decimal separator is `,`, not `.`.

Comment: While this will work, it would be interesting to investigate the _why_ behind the issue in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it's somehow linked with the locale of my PC (it's ru-RU), so the decimal separator becomes ','